# Copy gives me "are the same" error

Tags: find, cp, file-copy

```
find . -type f -iname "*.jpg" -exec cp {} JPG \;
```

I'm working on a shell script and I get an error on copying image files to a new directory: `are the same`

Comment: You have `.jpg` files in the `JPG` directory. You either need to prune that directory or use `-maxdepth 1` so that it doesn't look in subdirectories.

Comment: Saw you learned how to post code Since in your [homework challenge-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59346343/error-for-picture-already-exist-and-not-printing-results-of-my-count-to-a-file) you created the `JPG` directory just before copying, it may be allowed to delete it if already exists. So you can run tests over and over.

Answer (score 1):

The `JPG` directory is in the current directory. You are recursively searching the current directory with `find`.  This means that any file in `JPG` with a name matching `*.jpg` (case-insensitively) will be copied to itself.

To avoid this, use

```
find . -path ./JPG -prune -o -type f -iname '*.jpg' -exec cp {} ./JPG \;
```

This would remove the `JPG` directory from the search tree (i.e. not consider it for searching) whenever it is found.

---

To speed the operation up a bit, if you have GNU `cp`, you could use

```
find . -path ./JPG -prune -o -type f -iname '*.jpg' -exec cp -t ./JPG {} +
```

This would call `cp` with batches of found JPEG files, instead of once per found file.

A similar effect could be had with a single call to `rsync`:

```
rsync -av --exclude=/JPG --include='*.jpg' --include='*/' --exclude='*' ./ ./JPG
```

(although this would not do the `*.jpg` matching case-insensitively, unless you change `--include='*.jpg'` to `--include='*.[jJ][pP][gG]'`).

Comment: I'll give a try and thank you very much